# A dictionary of deferred promises

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I need to build PDF with images. I thought it was possible to provide links to locally stored files, but (please correct me, I'd be so happy) it turned out that PDFmake can only work with data:URI encoded images.
So now I have to convert the images, BUT they have to be loaded first, otherwise I'm converting a blank nothing.

Idea is that PDF building code is put into brackets of
`$.when.apply(null, imgData).done(function() { });`
AFAIK, images could be loaded randomly, so to prevent messing their order up, I put them into a dictionary where the key to each value is the index from intital *imgSources* array.
Now, It's my first time using `Deferred` class and `$.when`, so please correct my wrong usage.

```
function toDataUrl(src) {
    var img = new Image(),
    deferred = $.Deferred();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        deferred.resolve(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = src;
    return deferred.promise();
}

function makepdf() {
    var pdfContent, a = [], b = [], kontent = [],
        list = $("#tabs ul>li a"),
        imgSources = ['images/weledu.jpg'],
        imgData = {};
    $.getJSON(get_url+'types.php?id='+$('#type').val(), function (newsrc) {
        imgSources.push('images/lamps/'+newsrc.data['0'].image);
        $.each(imgSources, function(index, src) {
            imgData.index = toDataUrl(src);
        });
    });

    $.when.apply(null, imgData).done(function() {
        // pdf creation
    });     
};
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the callback passed to `.done()`, the `imgData` object is still blank there! Where am I mistaken? Isn't it supposed to be *done*?

Comment: `Function.prototype.apply` doesn't apply objects, it applies arrays.

Comment: @zzzzBov fine, but how can I be sure which imag's URI am I taking right now out of a resulting array? I'd gladly accept suggestions

Comment: Looking at the overall problem you are solving, you many be better off uploading the images and create the PDF server-side. We do that in our commercial apps.

Comment: @GoneCoding Wait. First thing - the images are stored on server, nothing is "uploaded". Second thing - please explain "server-side" better, I don't understand. Do you mean using PHP and it's libs to create PDF or?

Comment: Yes, using server-side libs to create the PDF. Moving them all down to the client browser, just to process a PDF, seems a very long way around the problem, but hey, it's PHP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.  One is that you cannot use `$.when.apply` with objects (dictionaries), only arrays.  Another is that when you call `$.when.apply`, your AJAX call isn't done yet, so `imgData` doesn't even have any data in it.

What happens is that when you pass an *empty* object to `$.when.apply`, it will be treated as a resolved promise (as it would be like you called `$.when()` with no parameters) and thus immediately call your `.done()` method.  This all happens *before* `$.getJSON` finishes.  (see docs for `$.when`: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Something else to note is that in JavaScript, objects are *unordered*, that is you cannot always guarantee you will loop over it in the same order every time.  For guaranteed order, you need an array.

One more thing to mention is that `imgData.index = toDataUrl(src);` doesn't do what you think it does.  This adds a key called `"index"` to your object, it does not use the *value* of `index`.  To do what you were expecting, use `imgData[index] = toDataUrl(src);`.

So, one solution here is to put your `$.when.apply` *inside* your `$.getJSON` and change `imgData` to an array.

Note that `$.when` will *keep* the order of the parameters you pass it (or in this case the array you "applied" to it).  In the `.done()` callback, you will be passed the parameters (the `dataURL` values) in the correct order.

```
function makepdf() {
    var pdfContent, a = [], b = [], kontent = [],
        list = $("#tabs ul>li a"),
        imgSources = ['images/weledu.jpg'],
        imgData = [];

    $.getJSON(get_url+'types.php?id='+$('#type').val(), function (newsrc) {
        imgSources.push('images/lamps/'+newsrc.data['0'].image);

        $.each(imgSources, function(index, src) {
            imgData.push(toDataUrl(src));
        });

        // I've always passed `$` as the 1st parameter here, 
        // not sure if it matters
        $.when.apply($, imgData).done(function(img1, img2) {
            // pdf creation
            // Use `img1`, `img2`, etc. here
            // Or loop over `arguments` to get the `dataURL`s
        });     
    });
}
```

Comment: What about loading order? It's still unpredictable. Also, you didn't get my idea with keys: I wasn't going to *loop* through resulting dict, I was going to access precise elements, because their keys are in same order that initial array.  
I am not obsessed with dictionaries and will gladly switch to using array, just assure me pls that the order will be preserved

Comment: What do you mean by "loading order"?  Do you mean that `toDataUrl()` may finish one image before the other?

Comment: Yeah I mean the onload order, kinda

Comment: The order will be preserved, check the docs for `$.when` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).  In your `.done()` callback, it will be passed parameters in the order the deferreds were passed to it.